# Is there a better solution, than the naive, for finding errors in an array order?

Tags: arrays, data-structures

I was given in an interview the following question, I am given an array of integers, and I need to return the number of integers in the array that are not in the index they would have been if the array was sorted.

For example for the array [1,1,3,4,1], I need to return 3 because the last three integers (3,4,1) are not in the indexes they would have been if the array was sorted, [1,1,1,3,4].
And for [5,4,3,2,1], I need to return 4, ([1,2,3,4,5]).

I only came up with the naive solution which is to copy the original array and then sort it and compare the two arrays and then count the number of different elements in every index.
It takes O(nlogn) time and O(n) space.

It feels to me like maybe I am missing something, and there might be a better solution. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

***Naive implies lacking in wisdom/judgment; a simple, elegant solution obtained under pressure is the opposite.***

There may be room for improvement but if it exists it is less likely to be "obvious" and probably isn't simple.  (My experiment below doesn't prove anything except that I haven't seen it;-)

**Thinking**
For an item to be in place, the number of greater items to its left (preceding it in the array) must equal the number of lesser items to its right.

Obviously this can be determined without needing a second array. Code below has better space complexity O(1) but time complexity is worse O(n^2). Forgive the cramped style and recursion but I'm trying to be terse.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
  static class Program
  {
    private static int itemVisits;
    static string PrintArray(int[] arr)
    {
      var sb = new StringBuilder("[");
      foreach (var i in arr)
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}, ", i);
      sb.Length -= 2;// kill last comma and space
      sb.Append("]");
      return sb.ToString();
    }

    static void Test(int[] arr)
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"{PrintArray(arr)}...");
      Console.WriteLine($"  method1: {ItemsOutOfPlace1(arr)} elements out of place, {itemVisits} item visits");
//      Console.WriteLine($"  method2: {ItemsOutOfPlace2(arr)} elements out of place, {itemVisits} item visits");
    }

    static int ItemsOutOfPlace1(int[] arr)
    {
      int countOutOfPlace = 0;
      itemVisits = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        countOutOfPlace += NeedToMove(arr[i], i) != 0 ? 1 : 0;
      return countOutOfPlace;

//  In place functions follow...
      int NeedToMove(int val, int i) { return CountRightLessThan(val, i + 1) - CountLeftGreaterThan(val, i - 1); }

      int CountRightLessThan(int val, int i)
      {
        if (i >= arr.Length) return 0;
        itemVisits++;
        return (arr[i] < val ? 1 : 0) + CountRightLessThan(val, i + 1);
      }

      int CountLeftGreaterThan(int val, int i)
      {
        if (i < 0) return 0;
        itemVisits++;
        return (arr[i] > val ? 1 : 0) + CountLeftGreaterThan(val, i - 1);
      }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Test(new []{ 1,1,3,4,1 });
      Test(new []{ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 });
      Test(new []{ 2,3,4,1,6,7,8,9,5 });
      Test(new []{ 30,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,1 });

      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

producing

```
[1, 1, 3, 4, 1]...
  method1: 3 elements out of place, 20 item visits
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]...
  method1: 4 elements out of place, 20 item visits
[2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5]...
  method1: 9 elements out of place, 72 item visits
[30, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 1]...
  method1: 2 elements out of place, 870 item visits
```

Strictly T(n(n-1)).  I tried to improve on this (you'll probably have spotted the commented out reference to `ItemsOutOfPlace2()`) but without a sort, achieved only *best case* time O(nlog(n)) and that required going back to O(n) space and a lot more, less elegant code.

**Conclusion**

1. Without formal analysis, there is no easy/obvious way to improve on both your space and time complexity. (If there is, it probably must add to code complexity).
2. Informal analysis says that every item has to be "positioned" and if you could do this more cheaply than in O(nlogn) time for arbitrary data, you'd have discovered a new worst-case-better-than-O(nlogn) sort algorithm.
3. My "naive" solution *improves only on space and at the cost of time*.  Yours is preferable unless an array allocation really can't be afforded.  Also, yours can employ any sort algorithm, so if you happen to know that the data is often nearly sorted, you could use a sort that exploits this like Timsort or Block sort, with time complexity for such input approaching O(n).

Nice question